# Two rows ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a two-row `ConstraintLayout`, each row has two views.  The problem with what I have now is the left views is overlapping the right views, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would like the left views (title, date) to stop where the download image and duration start.  I haven't worked with `ConstraintLayouts` much so it might be something easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to achieve this, one way would be to constraint your text into the image and give them the same height.

**They won't overlap each other if you will do something like this :**

In your example, you used `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on the text so it was expanded throw all of the row and overlapped your other view.
You should use `android:layout_width="0dp"` (it is `match_constraint`) so your views won't overlap each other.

**Here is an example of a layout that looks like the row you want to achieve:**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="loot at this text that wont everlap the image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks!